# Rails: How to know which route will be 'called'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm still trying to get to grips with Rails (Sorry to those people whose answers I haven't yet accepted. I assume you're right, but I haven't yet understood your answers).

I think my problem is I don't know how to tell which route will be 'triggered' when a user clicks a page element.

I understand how routes are mapped to paths, and how the paths (depending on the http verb) point to different controllers and actions.

I don't understand what decides which ROUTE is called.

Specifically, in my project I'm trying to display a set of quiz questions. When a user clicks the submit button, which part of the code determines which route is triggered? (I don't mean the path - I know that's mapped in config/routes.db - I'd like to know which ROUTE is triggered).

I know this might seem like a general question, but not understanding this is directly affecting my ability to progress a Rails project I'm developing.

Can anyone tell me what determines the ROUTE that gets sent into Rails? Is it the object type or resource that the current page is dealing with? I just can't tell. I assume there's something fundamental that I'm not 'getting' but I don't know what that is.

I have been reading the Hartl book and the 'getting started with Rails' guides, but I have not yet come across an explanation that has clarified this for me.

Comment: A route *is* the mapping from path to controller / action.

Comment: Generally `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` is a rack application that performs dispatching, it's not documented well but still you can have a look at source codes.

Comment: I think I must not be asking the right question. I'd like to know which route is triggered when I click the submit button of a form and how do I determine that? I'm using Devise for the form, so is it something internal to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `<form>` element that the `form_for` helper builds you will see that it has a method and action attribute set by the `form_for` helper.

The method attribute for creating and editing objects is set to `post` and the action is set depending on the state of the object passed in to the `form_for` helper.

When you pass a new instance of an object e.g. `form_for @post do |f|` the action attribute will have the value `/posts`. Rails routes will see this and know to route to the `create` method in the posts controller.

When an object of an existing post is given to the `form_for` helper the action attribute will have the value `/posts/:id`. When a user clicks submit the form will post to that action and rails routes will know that your posting/updating a post that already exists. Rails routing and will route to the `update` method of the posts controller and put the posts id into the params hash.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. At the moment I'm passing [current_user] to the form so when I click submit it goes to the user's profile. I need to get more familiar with the idea of Rails just 'knowing' stuff. I'd like to know what it's doing and I'm not used to objects/URLs/helpers seemingly appearing out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses the type of request (`GET/POST/PUT/DELETE`) and the url to determine which rules in your `routes.rb` matches that specific combination. It then dispatches the request to the appropriate controller action.

For a detailed understanding on defining your routes, the [official guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks. So where does it get the URL from? I'm using a Devise form, so the submit button is just f.submit("Get my results"). How (or where) does that generate a URL?